# Making reports in winforms and query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have two tables in access table : one contains partyname,Address,opening balance and table two contains partyname,netamount,creditamount,debitamount,final amount.

```
table 1                           | table 2                           
partyname  address openingbalance | partyname  netamount  creditamount debitamount finalamo

Pinakin    aaa       5000         | Pinakin     10000     100          1000        9100
Mitesh     bbb       7000         | Pinakin     5000      500             0        5500
                                  | Pinakin     15000     5000         500         19500
                                  | Mitesh      10000     2000            0        12000
                                  | Mitesh      3000      0            500         2500
```

I want query which give me result like this ( I want to make the reports in winforms using c#):

```
Partyname address Openingbalance netamount creditamount debitamount finalamount

Pinakin   aaa      5000          30000     5600          1500       39100
Mitesh    bbb      7000          13000     2000           500       21500

total              12000         43000     7600          2000       60600
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT table1.partyname, 
       max(table1.address), 
       sum(table2.netamount), 
       sum(table2.creditamount), 
       sum(table2.debitamount)
  FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.partyname = table2.partyname
 GROUP BY table1.partyname
```

Comment: You have not Added Openingbalance And final Amount